# Magento 1.8 admin user name and password right but not redirect to dashboard

Tags: magento-1.8, admin

After migrate live server to locahost admin user name and password right but not redirect to dashboard.

1. When i enter `http//127.0.01/magento/admin` it automatically move to `http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/`, but `http//127.0.01/magento/index.php/admin` working.
2. In this link `http//127.0.01/magento/index.php/admin` admin panel **username** and **password** right but not redirect to dashboard.

I clear all cache files in `var/cache` folder and session files `var/session` folder.

In `core_config_data` also changed like

1. `web/unsecure/base_url` as
   `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`
2. `web/secure/base_url` as
   `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`

And also changed **database name, username, password** in local.xml

Comment: Please check yout .htaccess file setting

Comment: Thanks for replay in .htaccess what i want to do..?

Comment: I think you have set redirection for index.php just comment this code as execute

Comment: You mean `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` this code

Comment: yes if you not need to htaccess please just rename it and run if not run so comment this code

Comment: Now i commend that code but when enter `http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin` showing **404 error**

Answer (score 1):

Please check cookie domain value from Database

```
Table: core_config_data
```

search in `path` column

```
web/cookie/cookie_domain
```

and set value to NULL

Comment: Thanks for replay It does not have this field @Nalin

Comment: Then, please try to remove `var/cache` and `var/session` folders

Comment: Also check for any error in `var/log`

Comment: removed `var/cache` , `var/session` and  `var/log` not working

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin/index/index/key/579c647a8baf2ae5d71c145cc4c9387e/` this is the link i got